# Connecting to ElasticSearch plugin under proxy settings

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, proxy

I have a problem with connecting to Elasticsearch under proxy settings. I have installed Bigdesk plugin manually with `bin/plugin -DproxyHost=myproxy.proxy.com -DproxyPort=80 --install lukas-vlcek/bigdesk`, everything went all right with it.

I run my Elasticsearch on docker, it generated some private IP.
After `http://[GeneratedIP]:9200/_plugin/bigdesk/` I have `error 504, Proxy Timeout` in web browser console.
After running ElasticSearch locally with `service elasticsearch start` and then in browser `http://localhost:9200/_plugin/bigdesk/` it stops loading and I can see just white screen, no output in inspect-console.

Any ideas?

Comment: what version of docker are you using? On which OS? Linux directly, or through VMs on Windows or Mac?

Comment: I use Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa directly. Docker version: latest with RedHat on it.

Comment: OK so no issue of port forwarding then. Maybe an issue with a net listener which does not listen a on all ports?

Comment: I don't know if I check proper thing, but after `netstat -l` I get [...] `[::]:9200, 9300, 9201, 9301`.

Comment: Is the docker daemon configured with the same proxy as Bigdesk plugin is using?

Comment: I don't know how to check what proxy is Bigdesk plugin using. If it is web browser's proxy then answer is yes.

Comment: I was referring to the proxy you mention in `bin/plugin -DproxyHost=myproxy.proxy.com -DproxyPort=8`